# (G.Analytics) How to add custom information to _addItem in ecommerce transaction

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

When submitting a transaction (a new order) to Google Analytics, I'd like to add a custom parameter to the product item.

The _addItem accepts the following parameters [as explained here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addItem):

transactionId, sku, name, category, price, quantity

I'd like to add a couple of custom parameters to this list (e.g. size, weight) - is this possible? Or should I use _setCustomVar [as explained here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)

Thanks

Comment: You should upgrade to the current version of the tracking code. That way you could upload extended product properties in a csv file and have them matched  to transaction data via the product sku, so you wouldn't have to set them in the code at all. As the asynchronous code is deprecated and does not support all Features of Universal Analytics you should not use it to implement new stuff.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks. Although I seem to have a fundamental issue with my understanding here. Are my code examples 'asynchronous' examples? I can't find much info on the Universal versions of these ecommerce methods - do I need to start my research again but into Universal Analytics instead?

Comment: @EikePierstorff _That way you could upload extended product properties in a csv file and have them matched to transaction data via the product sku, so you wouldn't have to set them in the code at all._ Where would I be uploading the csv to? Wouldn't it be _easier_ to set it in code rather than have the hassle of uploading a csv etc?

Comment: Would it ? You'd have to upload the csv data once via Data Import in the property settings and the data would be added automatically to all incoming data. This might be easier than pulling it from your backend systems, inserting them in the tracking code and submit it to Google.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Sounds like you're right. The site is actually already on Universal Analytics. Guessing I need to be looking at [Enhanced Ecommerce - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) for this?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I can't seem to find anything in the Google docs about adding product data via csv and relating it to the tracked data, do you have a source for this? Thanks

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en, specifically "product data import". I'm pretty sure you need to switch to the new tracking code to use this.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Many thanks, I will be taking this route.